# PHP привести signed int к unsigned?

Tags: php

Как можно отрицательное значение привести к беззнаковому?

-1000 = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$int = -1000;
echo sprintf("%u", $int); //4294966296
```

Из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php): u - аргумент трактуется как целое и выводится в виде десятичного числа без знака.

Стоит учесть, что результат на 32 битных системах и 64 будет различаться.
Все зависит от PHP_INT_MAX int(2147483648) в 32-битных системах и int(9223372036854775808) в 64-битных. Доступна начиная в версии PHP 7.0.0

Comment: а не 18446744073709550616?

Comment: 18446744073709550616 - это не unsigned long?

Comment: sprintf("%u", -1000)

Comment: У меня выводит 4294966296

Comment: у меня ubuntu 64